# Connecting to mongodb replica set outside kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I have some services which are inside a minikube cluster and I also have mongodb on the same local machine which is run with docker-compose but is outside the cluter. I am trying to access the db in this apps with a connection string. The problem is that I can't use replica set for some reason. When I pass in connection string `mongodb://host.minikube.internal:27017` to my service this way it works fine but if I add `?replicaSet=rs0` at the end it wouldn't connect. Does anyone know what can be the reason?

`docker-compose.yml` file looks like that:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    hostname: mongodb
    image: mongo:4.0
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: mongod --replSet rs0 --bind_ip_all
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
  configuremongoreplset:
    image: mongo:4.0
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb
    volumes:
      - ./ops-tools:/tools
    environment:
      - REPL_SET=rs0
      - MONGOD_MASTER_HOSTNAME=mongodb
    entrypoint: ['/tools/setup-replica-set.sh']

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local
```

A script to configure replica set:

```
MONGOD_MASTER=`getent ahosts ${MONGOD_MASTER_HOSTNAME} | head -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`

mongo --host $MONGOD_MASTER << EOF
  const config = {
    _id: "$REPL_SET",
    protocolVersion: 1,
    members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "$MONGOD_MASTER:27017" }
    ]
  };

  try {
    rs.conf();
    rs.reconfig(config, { force: true });
  } catch (e) {
    rs.initiate(config);
  }
EOF
```

I pass in the connection string in my deployment file like that :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: cms
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cms
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cms
    spec:
      containers:
          env:
            - name: CONNECTION_STRING
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: "mongodb-secret"
                  key: "connectionString"
```